# android authentication Sharepoint

Tags: android

My boss give me a url:http://sharepoint/appviewdocument/_vti_bin/sadadadw.svc/adwadadawd, Login name and password, and ask me to get data from the url to android.
how can I finlish it?

Comment: We are not here to do your job for you

Comment: Fire yourself, before your boss does.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer posted by gazgas in [HttpClient 4.1.1 returns 401 when authenticating with NTLM, browsers work fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917356/httpclient-4-1-1-returns-401-when-authenticating-with-ntlm-browsers-work-fine).
That's what I'm looking for.Cheers